# t to doSwi-Prolog I can't solve exercise

Tags: prolog

Pizzeria offers five types of pizzas:

- Hawaii - 25.90
- Capricciosa - 20.90
- Margherita - 9.90
- Pepperoni - 27.90
- Wege - 14.90

John, Anna and Kate made the following order:

- John - hawaii, pepperoni
- Anna - capriciosa, margherita
- Kate - hawaii

Calculate:

- how much each paid
- how much total they paid
- who paid the most
- which pizza was the most popular
- which pizza they did not choose

What I made:

```
% facts
pizza(hawaii, 25.90).
pizza(capricciosa, 20.90).
pizza(margherita, 9.90).
pizza(pepperoni, 27.90).
pizza(wege, 14.90).

% separate pizzas with persons (1)
person(john, hawaii).
person(john, pepperoni).
person(anna, capriciosa).
person(anna, margherita).
person(kate, hawaii).
% or list of pizzas with persons? (2)
person(john, [hawaii, pepperoni]).
person(anna, [capriciosa, margherita]).
person(kate, [hawaii]).

% predicates
% In simple excercises I don't have problems, but now I don't know what to do.
```

My question is what can (or should) I do to calculate this things.

```
% this returns cost of pizza ordered by Person
cost(Person, Cost) :- person(Person, Pizza), pizza(Pizza, Cost)
```

What would I want to do:

- how much each paid

Ask question:

```
?- each_paid(john, Cost).
Cost = 53.8.
```

What I think should I do:

> 1. Get pizza from list in person fact
> 2. Get price of pizza and add to Cost
> 3. Get next pizza and go to 2

```
% (1)
% person(john, hawaii).
% person(john, pepperoni).
each_paid(Person, Cost) :- person(Person, Pizza), pizza(Pizza, Cost2), add Cost2 to Cost and find another pizza
```

or

```
% (2)
% person(john, [hawaii, pepperoni]).
each_paid(Person, Cost) :- person(Person, [Head|Tail]), pizza(Head, Cost2)
```

add `Cost2` to `Cost` and find another pizza
in (2) way error occurs when it try finding `person(john, [pepperoni])` which does not exist and I also need (1) facts.

Comment: Aaand what is your actual question?

Comment: edited question, I have a lot of time. Beginner in prolog

Comment: Your question is way to broad. We won't do your homework for you. Grab a book about Prolog and learn. Downvoting.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all to write some predicates/rules to solve this? It would be good to dig in and try some things.

Comment: I have tried many solutions but none worked.

Comment: This language is strange.

Comment: Perhaps you could show one of your better attempts? Then someone here could explain your misunderstanding. Prolog is only strange if you don't understand it. If you study it, it's strangeness disappears and it becomes something interesting and nice. :)

Comment: If your Prolog has library(aggregate), and you're allowed to use it, each question is easily solved. Otherwise, you should start building the basic blocks you need to answer the questions.

First collect every relevant info in a list, then compute the values and compare them. It's going to a fairly difficult task, I think...